# How to run a python script inside Applescript?

Tags: python, applescript

I had to do an Applescript and by the end of it i just want to run a python script.

I wrote

```
do shell script "/Users/Tom/Desktop/ayscript.py"
```

But it's said "permission denied"

Any idea ?

Comment: You don't have permission

Comment: It's my script and my computer ! Off course I have permission how to explain that to Applescript ?

Comment: Why don't I have permission and how to solve that problem ?

Comment: Can you try running the script with elevated priviledges? Equivalent of `sudo` in Unix.

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to run the script directly instead of using Python to run it. You need to do shell script `python`, passing the path to your script as an argument.

```
do shell script "python /Users/Tom/Desktop/ayscript.py"
```

Comment: Thanks finally I put that which is working    : "  do shell script "/usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/xxx/xxx.py"