# Regex- Match any n characters in (not-necessarily consecutive) sequential order?

Tags: regex, applescript

Consider the following string: 3ccc-8ab9-6335-b7af

I'm trying to figure out a regular expression that matches if any 6 characters are in their proper location, but not necessarily consecutive. For example, each of the following would be considered a match:

- `3ccc-8`cn4-o8cy-5234
- `3ccc`&`8a`b9-6335-b7af
- 39kf`-`k32p`-6335`-3l10
- `3c`08`-`a0m3`-`fd`35`-4g17

I'm sorry, I'm really very new to this, it's outside of my area of expertise. The things I've tried already are not even close and so amateurish, I'm sure they can't be of help.

Applescript is preferred. I've only done a couple of small scripting projects before to automate certain processes related to laboratory data.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Put language in the tags.

Comment: Language is important here. Regex isn't the best tool for this job. Anything you post helps us understand what you're trying to accomplish, maybe things you've tried, it may trigger ideas for us to go about your problem to help you resolve the issue.

Comment: I'm not familiar with AppleScript, but if you can use python or convert this python script into AppleScript, this should work for you. [See the python script in use here](https://tio.run/##VY5BDoIwEEXXnVNMWAhEmiAFBRNOQliUSpUAbVMxAS@PIGrict7//2XMNNy0YvN8xxxdJoSgKa8yemQsodWJSxe6JSmAOO9QCxVTnYqJJhGLneDDd/@jjWetpC2LzMZZdwg//TClPOwZlZeFx9fDyYES4FJLFLo33NYeD7Dyz0Ds@pULRGqLY4ATNgqfjfnlpJE4Yp7jtB7E7vNxGdXDwyq0AMY2avCKr/Ue9D6uqn71dKU/zy8). Some modifications are necessary, but the scaffolding is there. Not *exactly* sure what you consider a *match*.

Comment: `that matches if any 6 characters are in their proper location` Care to elaborate on what this means ?

Comment: Put capture's around each like `(?:(3)|.)(?:(c)|.) ...` After the match, concatenate all the groups `string str = $1a+$2+$3...` If length of string is greater or equal to 6, you have a match. This is lightning fast. Alternatively, replace the match with `$1$2$3...` if new string length >=6 you have a winner.

Comment: In example 1: `3ccc-o...` why does the `o` match? I guess it's a typo. Two following dashes seem to match.

Comment: Ya the matches don't make much sense with the question. Look at the python script in my previous comment, they're nothing close. I understand I'm grabbing all matches (not just first six), but even the first six aren't matching correctly. [See here with *correct* output for first 6 chars](https://tio.run/##VY7LCoMwEEXXma8YXFSlBqzx1YJfIi5ialpRk5Ba0P681b6gyzn33sOYebxqxZblhgW6TAhBc14facpYQuuMSxf6NSmBOK9QCxVTnYuZJhGLneDDd/@jNz92knYsMm/O@kP46Yc55eHAqDyvPL4cMgcqgHMjUejBcNt4PMDaPwGx21cuEKktTgHO2Cp8tOaXk1bihEWB83YQuy@mddSMd6vQAhjbqtErv9ZbMPhleEor3HzDJusrf1me).

Comment: Why not just run my python script by calling it in AppleScript as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23108335/how-to-run-a-python-script-inside-applescript) suggests?

Comment: @userunknown that's not a valid expression or doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @userunknown you'd need to use another set of square brackets as well. The notation is `[[:digit:]]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166127/discussion-between-user-unknown-and-ctwheels).

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925

Comment: Find `(?:(3)|.)(?:(c)|.)(?:(c)|.)(?:(c)|.)(?:(-)|.)(?:(8)|.)(?:(a)|.)(?:(b)|.)(?:(9)|.)(?:(-)|.)(?:(6)|.)(?:(3)|.)(?:(3)|.)(?:(5)|.)(?:(-)|.)(?:(b)|.)(?:(7)|.)(?:(a)|.)(?:(f)|.)` replace `${1}${2}${3}${4}${5}${6}${7}${8}${9}${10}${11}${12}${13}${14}${15}${16}${17}${18}${19}` Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   1
Elapsed Time:    0.16 s,   162.91 ms,   162908 µs
Matches per sec:   306,921

Answer (score 0):

This is not a job for regular expressions.

To match 123 at 2 positions you have the alternatives:

```
12-
1-3
-23
```

This can be expressed with matching at the first position, and then matching at one of the following positions `(1(2.)|(.3))` or ignoring the first position, but matching in the two last positions: `.23`, so the whole expressions is "`(1(2.)|(.3))|.23`". This grows rapidly out of control:

```
1234 match at 2 pos

12..
1.3.
1..4
.23.
.2.4
..34
```

Of course, you may write a program, which generates such an expression, but an alternative approach without regexes is so much simpler. Compare the strings, char by char, count, size >= 6, done? Easy to write, easy to understand. Here, the simple case for 2 matching positions in 3 is already leaving the trivial space.

Comment: If regex is a problem, it's because you've painted it as something used that needs permutations, which isn't true. Of course, using C and pointer arithmetic with a counter is ideal. What is _simpler_ ? I suggested a simple regex approach in a comment with a single length check. Couldn't get much simpler. Remember, _all_ regex engines are written is C and is very fast if you know how to use it.

Comment: Well, an 8 character expression, for each of the 19 positions, what could be much simpler? Let's write a program to do the task! Here is the chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166127/discussion-between-user-unknown-and-ctwheels

Comment: From what I gleaned, the OP has a constant template `3ccc-8ab9-6335-b7af` he want's to match at the fixed positions. Any 6 in the proper position is a winner.

Comment: @sln: No, I don't see permutations. Permutations - correct me, if I'm wrong, are reorderings of sets.

Comment: `k-permutations of n : A weaker meaning of the term permutation, sometimes used in elementary combinatorics texts` Your regex is a manifested representation of unique combination of capture groups, example. 4 groups total, where 2 must match, yielding {12},{13},{14},{23},{24},{34}. But, if you take out the forcing of an exact match with this:  `(?:(a)|.)(?:(b)|.)(?:(c)|.)(?:(d)|.)` it relieves the engine of a huge burden that can be absorbed on the  replacement side with a simple blind replacement `$1$2$3$4`. The length of the resulting string is the number of groups that matched.

Comment: Btw, you might have a typo on your regex there, should be `1(2.|.3)|.23`

Answer (score 0):

Your basic algorithm:

```
to isMatch(theText, thePattern, requiredCount)
    -- (this assumes both strings are equal length)
    set foundCount to 0
    repeat with i from 1 to length of thePattern
        if character i of theText equals character i of thePattern then
            set foundCount to foundCount + 1
            if foundCount = requiredCount then return true
        end if
    end repeat
    return false
end isMatch


set theList to {¬
    "3ccc-ocn4-o8cy-5234", ¬
    "o8cy-5234-3ccc-ocn4", ¬
    "3ccc&8ab9-6335-b7af", ¬
    "39kf-k32p-6335-3l10", ¬
    "3c08-a0m3-fd35-4g17", ¬
    "3ccc-xxxx?xxxx?xxxx", ¬
    "3ccc-xxxx?xxxx-xxxx"}

set thePattern to "3ccc-8ab9-6335-b7af"

set foundItems to {}
repeat with textRef in theList
    set theText to contents of textRef
    if isMatch(theText, thePattern, 6) then
        set end of foundItems to theText
    end if
end repeat
return foundItems
```

Result:

```
{"3ccc-ocn4-o8cy-5234", 
 "3ccc&8ab9-6335-b7af", 
 "39kf-k32p-6335-3l10", 
 "3c08-a0m3-fd35-4g17", 
 "3ccc-xxxx?xxxx-xxxx"}
```